# Linq to dataset and display linq result in repeater control

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I need to display distinct rows, which actually should get 1 latest rows  for each year based for date fields.

I tried to get resolve this using CTE but on further testing it is not working properly as it will gets only the ROW based on ROWNumber and if we use filter then it doesn't get the desired results.

So i thought of getting the AlbumID, AlbumName, AlbumDate and AlbumYear_YYYY from table and pass it to dataset and then use LINQ againt this dataset to further get the unique rows based on latest album for the year YEAR only

Assuming my Table has following rows

AlbumID, AlbumName, AlbumDate , AlbumIcon

MY MS-SQL query

```
string sql= "SELECT AlbumID, AlbumName, AlbumIcon, AlbumDate, DATEPART(YYYY, AlbumDate) AS Year FROM PhotoAlbumName "

DataSet ds = DataProvider.Connect_Select(strSql);
DataView dv = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
```

//DO LINQ HERE and pass the value of linq to  Pager control

```
 PagerControl1.BindDataWithPaging(rptAlbumsCategories, dv.Table);
```

I am not sure how to do this but if it works then it will eliminate the unwanted result which happens due to following sql query.

```
;WITH DistinctYEAR AS
(
    SELECT AlbumID, AlbumIcon, AlbumDate, AlbumVisible,AlbumName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY,AlbumDate) ORDER BY AlbumDate) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM PhotoAlbumName 
)
SELECT * FROM DistinctYEAR WHERE RowNum = 1 AND AlbumVisible = 1 ORDER BY AlbumDate DESC
```

UPDATE:

Comment: Does your "UPDATE" mean that your answer is already answered now? Apart from that, i assume that your cte is incorrect. You should apply the `Where` clause to the `CTE` not on the outer `SELECT`.

Comment: No, I just added a link where user also wanted to get unique data based on date field but using link. t doesn't show complete example...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure  but i  assume that your cte is incorrect. You should apply the `WHERE AlbumVisible = 1`  on the `CTE` not on the outer `SELECT`:

```
;WITH DistinctYEAR AS
(
    SELECT AlbumID, AlbumIcon, AlbumDate, AlbumVisible,AlbumName,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY,AlbumDate) ORDER BY AlbumDate) AS 'RowNum'
    FROM PhotoAlbumName
    WHERE AlbumVisible = 1  
)
SELECT dy.* 
FROM DistinctYEAR dy 
WHERE RowNum = 1
ORDER BY AlbumDate DESC
```

Comment: Now it gets me the all the rows per year but It gets me the partial results as it still is not sorting properly by `OVER(PARTITION BY DATEPART(YYYY,AlbumDate) ORDER BY AlbumDate DESC) AS 'RowNum'`

Comment: tim, It should get me album with dates `2012-11-26` but it gets me `2012-12-02` for year 2012. i am not sure how to make it work properly..